# Can the GetField() method of the PrivateObject class access a private const string in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test that accesses a file in isolated data storage. The file name is stored in a private const string within the class because I don't use it anywhere else in the whole application.

However, when I run my unit test I get a "Field not found" error when I call the GetField("fieldName") method of the PrivateObject class instance.

```
string historyFileName = (string)history.GetField("ISOLATED_HISTORY_FILE");
```

Comment: What type is history? A `Type`? And why does this code even compile? `GetField` returns a `FieldInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem for any one who may have the same issue. I changed the filed from private const string to private string. Apparently, reflection doesn't recognize fields marked with const. It isn't the name I gave the filed because I tried the test with ISOLATED_HISTORY_FILE and isolatedHistoryFile and it worked both ways.

Comment: you should use `static readonly` as suggested by @Aliostad and accept his answer.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Use the overload which you can pass `BindingFlags` and pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`.</s>

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx).

---

### UPDATE

I thought you have a field. `Const` does get replaced by the literal at compile-time. Change to `static readonly` and pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static`.

If you cannot change the source then there is no way

Comment: which BindingFlags do I use for a const. I tried private and static and both fail?

Answer (score 4):

Use `PrivateType` then call the `GetStaticField` method to retrieve the value of a private const.

Comment: Not sure why not marked as solution as this is the clearest solution given the  context that the original question is already using PrivateObject. 

You can't get private const from PrivateObject, but PrivateType is defined for this purpose.

Changing the fields access type to static readonly or just a private field is not an acceptable solution, you should not have to modify source code for the only purpose to make it unit testable.